# Whiptail --inputbox не отображается

Tags: linux, rpm

Использую программу *whiptail* для отображения пользовательского диалога при установке rpm пакета.
Для сборки rpm-пакета в *spec файле* в секции *%post* прописано

```
whiptail --title "Конфигурация хоста адаптеров" --clear --inputbox "Введите адрес сервера управления" --ok-button Далее --cancel-button Отмена 10 60 127.0.0.1 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3
```

То есть я ожидаю, что по окончании установки пакета должен отобразиться диалог.
Делаю успешную сборку пакета, приступаю к установке пакета на дистрибутив *opensuse*

Когда я устанавливаю пакет через команду

```
rmp -iv <packagename>
```

то все работает, диалог отображается.

Если я делаю установке с помощью команды

```
yum localinstall <packagename>
```

то диалог создается(установка ждет нажатие клавиши), но он не отображается на консоли.

В чем разница? Почему во втором случае диалог не отображается на консоли?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*rpm* — неинтерактивная программа (и библиотека). в её работе не предусмотрено взаимодействие с пользователем.

технически, разумеется, можно вставить в скрипты (*pretrans*, *pre*, *post*, *preun*, *postun* или *posttrans*) какой-нибудь интерактивный код, который удачно отработает в **некоторых** случаях.

но *rpm* (и бинарник, и *rpm-libs*) могут использоваться (и используются) *другими* программами, не расчитывающими на «проявления интерактивности» (та же *yum*, или, ещё лучше, какие-нибудь графические «обёртки»).

поэтому попытки вставить в скрипты код, ожидающий взаимодействия с пользователем — это плохая идея.

гораздо лучшая идея — включить в ваш пакет *отдельно запускаемую* интерактивную программу (скрипт), осуществляющую необходимую вам настройку/конфигурацию. и пусть пользователь запускает её самостоятельно **после** завершения установки пакета(-ов).

---

дополнительная информация:

- https://superuser.com/q/408852/454489
- https://www.redhat.com/archives/rpm-list/2003-September/msg00072.html
- https://www.redhat.com/archives/rpm-list/2001-May/msg00071.html

Comment: Спасибо, я учел ваше замечание. Но...
Я закинул вывод пользовательского диалога в скрипт userdialog.sh.
Теперь вызываю этот скрипт в post-скрипте
userdialog.sh &

Установка пакета проходит успешно. Но диалога по-прежнему нет, в случае, если я устанавливаю пакет через yum. Через rpm диалог успешно отображается.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov, вы хотите добиться от программы *yum*, чтобы она (хотя бы в текстовом режиме) запускала программу *rpm* так, чтобы та могла взаимодействовать с пользователем? тогда вам нужно внести необходимые вам изменения в программу *yum*.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov, перечитал ещё раз ваш комментарий. кажется, вы не поняли мой ответ в той части, что начинается с «гораздо лучшая идея». сейчас попробую переформулировать это место. **переформулировал**

Comment: Да, я вас сначала неправильно понял. Теперь стало понятно, спасибо.

Comment: Но все-таки, ведь я запускаю скрипт в фоне(`./userdialog &`), то есть установка пакета уже завершается, и вызывается этот скрипт в новом потоке... Но через yum этот диалог создается, но не отображается на экране, как будто диалог вывелся с полной прозрачностью.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov, тут может быть множество подводных проблем. первое, что приходит в голову — whiptail, скорее всего, работает через *readline*, для которого необходим полноценный *tty*. а *yum* при запуске *rpm* (или функций из *rpm-libs*), не предоставляет *rpm-у* такого доступа. предположим, вы как-то «победили» и вывели диалог. но в другой версии *yum-а* он может вновь не работать. а в графических «обёртках» вокруг *rpm-а* типа *yumex*, *yast*, *urpm* и т.п. диалог **точно** не будет работать, потому как *tty* там вообще отсутствует.

Comment: в общем, повторю ещё раз: программа (и библиотека) *rpm* **не расчитана** на интерактивную работу. и ни одна программа, её использующая, не содержит необходимой (отлаженной и заведомо работоспособной) функциональности.

Comment: благодарю за пояснение.